# returning dateTime in local time instead of UTC with gSOAP

Tags: c++, datetime, xsd, timezone, gsoap

I have a soap server that uses gSOAP. One of the requests contain an `xsd:dateTime` field in the response. This `dateTime` is always returned in UTC, but I want to return the `dateTime` in local time. I fill the field with the local time as `time_t`, but then converting this into `xsd:dateTime`, gsoap converts it into UTC automatically. Can I change this behavior?

In [this link](https://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/#toxsd7) it sounds like gsoap will always use UTC ("A `time_t` value is considered and represented in UTC by the serializer."). I also already searched through the flags [here](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc9.12), but I could not find a flag for my use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the implementation of the internal `soap_dateTime2s` function ([as found here](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP/blob/af73ab8e55c00b43556876de39bef5dd200d4ba9/gsoap/stdsoap2.c#L13163-L13231)), it appears to test several config flags (settable in [`config.h`](https://github.com/stoneyrh/gSOAP/blob/af73ab8e55c00b43556876de39bef5dd200d4ba9/config.h)).

I haven't tested, but it would seem that to get output in terms of local time, `HAVE_GMTIME_R` and `HAVE_GMTIME` need to be undefined.

Comment: Ok, this method is really strange. It doesn't sound like a good idea to change the formatting of the output depending on the platform. However, your proposal worked well. As I did not wanted to change which macros are activated, I basically changed the ordering of the if-blocks in order to prefer the one that worked for me (which was the one for HAVE_FTIME). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To use local time instead of gmt time, after `./configure` change `config.h` as below:

```
/* Define to 1 if you have the `gmtime' function. */
//#define HAVE_GMTIME 1
#undef HAVE_GMTIME

/* Define to 1 if you have the `gmtime_r' function. */
//#define HAVE_GMTIME_R 1
#undef HAVE_GMTIME_R
```

then make `gsoap`, now `soap_dateTime2s` will return time in local.

like

> 2017-10-24T02:28:41Z will be return as 2017-10-24T10:28:41+08:00

Answer (score -1):

It seems that what I want to have is not that easy. I assume I need to write my own custom serializer for `xsd:dateTime`, similar to the examples in [this link](https://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/#custom-3).

Still, if someone has a better solution or any suggestions on how to write such a serializer, please tell me your ideas.